# Why get new ordered array withoun changing old one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
          if (a > b) return 1;
          if (a == b) return 0;
          if (a < b) return -1;
    }

let per = [9.4, 9.7, 9.3, 4.5];
let perOrder = [];

perOrder = per.sort(compareNumeric);

console.log(per);
console.log(perOrder);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/kq3d9px2/

Now both arrays are [4.5, 9.3, 9.4, 9.7], but I need not changed [9.4, 9.7, 9.3, 4.5] too.

Comment: `let perOrder = per.slice().sort(compareNumeric);`

Comment: Also your sort logic equates to `return a - b;`